# Display More or Less Info on Screen Depending on Device Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Can someone please point me towards documentation on handling content on different screen sizes with ICS?  I want to display more or less on the screen dependent upon the device, for example a phone versus tablet versus tv.

Comment: Why did you down vote me?  I understand how to utilize Android docs, but am having difficulty finding relations to ICS specific docs. IE...is it advisable to build one app that handles all devices?

Comment: i up voted you :)  negative votes suck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starting point in the docs for the answer is the topic [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html). Take a look particularly at [Implementing Adaptive UI Flows](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html). There are also relevant Best Practices topics: [Supporting Tablets and Handsets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html) and [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use layout qualifiers if you want to display a different layout depending on the screen size. Look at this page for reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Essentially, create a `layout-xlarge` folder in your `res` directory and create a layout file with the same name you use in the `layout` directory. What this will do is check to see what kind of device is running, and if it's considered `xlarge` (10" tablet, tv) it will look in that folder first for its layout resource. If it doesn't qualify under a specific folder you have made (for instance, a `normal` size phone), it will default to the `layout` folder.